# dotnet publish won't copy files with copy task

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm trying to customize my `*.pubxml` profile of a `ASP.NET Core` project. To find out how it actually works I tried to copy a couple of random `*.log` files from one directory to the other. I once somehow managed to do it but I don't know what I have done and now I'm stuck. This won't copy any files.

I execute this profile with

```
dotnet publish MyCoolProject.csproj /p:PublishProfile=\Properties\PublishProfiles\TestProfile.pubxml
```

when I run it with `-v diag > pubxml.log` it creates a `25 MB` large log file and I can see all the `*.log` files that I want to copy listed there as:

```
   MyFiles
       c:\temp\test1.log
       c:\temp\test2.log
```

but it doesn't copy them.

This is my profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>ec190b7a-d5b4-43d3-a729-75e272037c05</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>c:\temp\bin\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win81-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <MyFiles Include="c:\temp\*.log" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyFiles">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyFiles)" DestinationFolder="c:\temp\test">
      <Output
          TaskParameter="CopiedFiles"
          ItemName="test" />
    </Copy>    
  </Target>    

</Project>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For running `Target` in `FolderProfile.pubxml`, try to specify the conditions like `BeforeTargets` or `AfterTargets`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyFiles Include="c:\temp\*.log" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyFiles)" DestinationFolder="c:\temp\test">
    <Output
        TaskParameter="CopiedFiles"
        ItemName="test" />
    </Copy>
</Target>
```

Comment: You are my hero today! ;-)